# Regex get split email parts preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

I have a regular explression like this one

```
$regex = '/(^info@)|(@onemore\.com)|(^someother@)|(@spam\.com)/i';
```

i need to get all matches in email string:
for example:

if i have an email like this one:

```
info@spam.com
preg_match_all($regex, 'info@spam.com', $matches);
```

should return an array with

```
1) info@
2) @spam.com
```

but it only return `info@` match

One more example if i do like this:

```
preg_match_all($regex, 'someother@spam.com', $matches);
```

result should contain

```
1)someother@
2)@spam.com
```

there are more combination but this is an expected  result.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a positive lookahead assertion in-order to do an overlapping match.

```
(?=^(.*@))|(@.*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/92)

**OR**

If you want a specific solution then you could use this,

```
(?=^((?:info|someother)@))|(@spam\.com$)
```

Grab the first and second parts from group index 1 and 2.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/93)

Comment: also one more question, what should i use if i need also match a full email `someemail@somedomain.com` ?